# How to increase file's content value by 1 using bash?

Tags: bash

I wrote this bash script, but it doesn't work.

```
dex=`date +%Y%m%d`

if [ -f "bv$dex.txt" ]; 

then
eval bv$dex=`cat ./bv$dex.txt`
let bv$dex+=1 ;
echo $bv$dex > ./bv$dex.txt

else
echo 1 > ./bv$dex.txt

fi
```

For some reason it just writes variable dex in file, instead of number + 1

Comment: This is the expected behavior since there is no variable named `bv$dex`, but can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do? It is possible to use [indirect expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for variable names, but it is quite complicated and absolutely unnecessary for the script you show: you can just use a different variable name. So, is this a simplified example of what you are really trying to do and, if so, what is it you are trying to do so we can see if we can find an alternative?

Comment: Also, in almost all cases where people think that indirect expansion is the answer, they should be using an array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you could avoid this by using a simpler variable name for the file name, like `counter=$(cat "bv$(date +%Y%m%d)")`.

But if you would like to understand why it doesn't work, the problem is this line:

```bsh
echo $bv$dex > ./bv$dex.txt
```

The command `echo $bv$dex` is evaluating `$bv` and `$dex` as two separate expressions, and concatenating the results. Note `$bv` is undefined, therefore it evaluates to `""` (empty string) *. So this is equivalent to `echo $dex` which just prints the date.

Instead, you would want

```bsh
eval echo \$bv$dex > ./bv$dex.txt
```

If `dex=20211228` (for example), then the expression `\$bv$dex` evaluates to the literal string `$bv20211228`, since the `\$` is treated as a literal `$` and not a variable reference. So this `eval` command then becomes `echo $bv20211228`, which yields the result you expect.

Just because this is possible though, doesn't mean it is a good idea :)

* If you add `set -u` to the top of your script, it will fail while evaluating, instead of evaluating to an empty string. I highly recommend adding `set -eu` as the first line of your scripts, right after the shebang `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

From the code given, the filename appears to be invariant once the date is known.

There is no merit in having the variable name match the file's basename.

```
#.. Create the full filename.
printf -v Fn 'bv%(%Y%m%d)T.txt' -1

#.. Create or fetch the serial number.
Num=0
[[ -r "${Fn}" ]] && read -r Num < "${Fn}"

#.. Write the incremented serial.
printf > "${Fn}" '%d\n' $(( ++Num ))
```